# http live mpeg 4 streaming on android phone creates out of memory error

Tags: android, bitmap, http-live-streaming

I am trying to implement http live video streaming on android 2.2
Apparently it turns out that there is no easy way out for this so i am creating a httpurlconnection for this and then fetching the multipart data and creating bitmap on the android screen. While creating the bitmap this is what i observe in logcat

while application is trying to fetch data and create bitmap i get this in logcat at 
regular intervals

11-30 15:55:31.330: ERROR/dalvikvm-heap(327): Out of memory on a 17842016-byte allocation.
initially starting from 6MB , then 9 MB then 12 MB and then the above after which the application force closes.

Comment: Are you recycling the bitmaps while creating new ones?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [vitamio](http://vov.io/vitamio/) yet, it is media lib for android, One of interesting feature it provided is enabling HTTP Live Streaming on android 2.1+. I've never used it myself, but worth to try and probably post some feedback for us.

> **Network Protocols**
>   The following network protocols are supported for audio and video playback:
>
> MMS
>   RTSP (RTP, SDP)
>   HTTP progressive streaming
>   HTTP live streaming (M3U8), for Android 2.1+

Comment: i have seen this application https://market.android.com/details?id=com.alexvas.dvr&hl=en and this does exactly what i want to do :( any leads on this one wud be appreciated

Comment: @abhishek, it is better to open new thread for asking new question instead of asking here in comments